# Python location-allocation

Tags: python, pysal

I have a geodataframe of polygons.

I need to create the smallest possible number of points (hydrants) so that the maximum distance between each point to the edge of a polygon is 100 m, and that from each point only a maximum of 5 polygons can be supplied.
I've been looking at `Pysal` but I don't think it does what I need, any ideas?

```
import geopandas as gpd
url = 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_58NHzUOW7T7RTxOK6KXx7-1KbDnh-kO/view?usp=drive_link'
url='https://drive.google.com/uc?id=' + url.split('/')[-2]
gdf = gpd.read_file(url)
```

I need to create the smallest possible number of points。